# Charging pins stuck in AirPods case

Tags: technology, repair

One of my AirPods in my AirPods Pro wasn’t charging recently, so I decided to check out the charging pins in the case. I tried fiddling with them using a toothpick attempting to remove any dust in them. However, I overdid it and one of the charging pins is now stuck inside the  case as shown in the following image:-

[image]
(You can see one charging pin is out and the other is stuck inside)

I am unable to remove it by tapping on the back of the case and I’ve even tried using a magnet to attract it. The AirPods are out of warranty so I’m not really intent on repairing it at an apple store because I’m pretty sure they’ll ask me to replace the entire case. What can I do?

Comment: The photo isn't too clear, but if that is a bit of toothpick stuck in there, try using fine-point tweezers or a sewing needle to dislodge it.

Comment: Please post a better photo

Answer (score 2):

The best answer in your case: since you are not skilled in doing precision repairs, please take your device to a professional, before you destroy it beyond repair. This is not about a hack anymore.